# PHP for directory listing

Tags: php, loops, directory, webdav, directory-listing

i wont to list a set of files in a directory and the files in its sub directory using a loop rather than the function 
as im getting the information about the directory through an xml based webdav and **php native functions are infertile** so please understand the issue has not yet been lodged here 
**$urlloc** is used to remove the same directory from being looped again

```
foreach ($xml as $key) {
if(empty($key->propstat->prop->resourcetype[0])){
    echo $key->href."<br/>";//files are printed, for debugging perposes im printing it
}else{
    $Nurlloc=$key->href;
    if ($Nurlloc!=$urlloc){
        echo "<b>".$Nurlloc."</b><br/>";//directorys printed in bold for debugging
        $urlloc=$Nurlloc;
        //gtndirdown()
```

above is the method im getting to know if its a directory or not 
**NOTE** i want to be able to make this code loop through and get me all the files in the directory i will also post the array of files im getting

```
[response] => Array
    (
        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [href] => /dav/product_images/
                [propstat] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [prop] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [resourcetype] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                            (
                                            )

                                    )

                                [quota-used-bytes] => 2147483647
                                [quota-available-bytes] => 2147483647
                            )

                        [status] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                    )

            )

        [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [href] => /dav/product_images/a/
                [propstat] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [prop] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [resourcetype] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                            (
                                            )

                                    )

                                [quota-used-bytes] => 2147483647
                                [quota-available-bytes] => 2147483647
                            )

                        [status] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                    )

            )
```

iv been stuck in this issue for 4 days and i have would like if some one could come up with a logic for this issue

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is an idea that you can implement in your logic

```
// the name of directory
$dir='path_to_your_directory';

$files = array_slice(scandir($dir), 2);
print_r($files);
```

Comment: the files are in a remote server my friend and only way of scanning the directory is through webdav and its stupid xml format 
i had to regex it and then convert it to an array for use in php 
im near 100% done with this right now 
there is no ftp access and i cant put any file in to the server ether
i hate this stupid format and there is no other alternative  
its like a bottleneck with only one answer annd i dont know it

Comment: Another hints, if you love array then use this easy solution to convert XML to Array $xml=json_decode(json_encode($xml),TRUE);

Comment: thats exactly what i did :)